# How can I make setTimeout work with negative numbers?

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout, polyfills

I can use `setTimeout` to make a message show up three seconds after I click a button, like this:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("You clicked the button three seconds ago.");
  }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

But for some reason, when I try to make the message show up three seconds *before* I click the button, it doesn't seem to work.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("You will click the button three seconds from now.");
  }, -3000);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

I expect the message to show up -3000 milliseconds after I click the button, that is, three seconds before I click the button, but actually it shows up immediately after I click the button. It seems that `setTimeout` doesn't support a negative second argument.

Is there any reason why it isn't working? Are there any workarounds or polyfills to support this missing functionality?

Comment: Obviously you forgot `import { setTimeout } from 'prescience-shim'`. It's very handy

Comment: Backwards time-travel does not exist

Comment: @CertainPerformance not according to that wonderful documentary _Time Cop_. Certainly you can't go forward because the future hasn't happened yet but backwards was entirely possible

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will cease to be a problem tomorrow.

Comment: @Nick you mean *yesterday*?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to import `capacitor` from the `flux` library.

Comment: You ever try raising a bug against that library? They always close them before you even get a chance